# Display custom HTML5 data attributes from selected radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to retrieve custom data attributes from selected `radio buttons` from multiple button groups and display them for the user.

Here is an example of the `radio buttons` I am working with:

```
<input type="radio" id="poolSmallButton" name="pool" class="calc" value="500" data-selection-name="Small Pool"/>
<input type="radio" id="poolMediumButton" name="pool" class="calc" value="1000" data-selection-name="Medium Pool"/>

<input type="radio" id="landscapingSmallButton" name="landscaping" value="100" class="calc" data-selection-name="Small Landscaping"/>
<input type="radio" id="landscapingMediumButton" name="landscaping" value="500" class="calc" data-selection-name="Medium Landscaping"/>

<span id="quote-items" name="quote-items"></span>
```

I am currently using this `jQuery` to extract the data attributes from the selected `radio buttons` but currently only the top-most `radio button` loaded in the `DOM` will only display as my output:

```
var itemNames = [$(".calc:checked").attr("data-selection-name")];
  $("#quote-items").text(itemNames)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use `.attr(key)` method it will always fetch you the value of first matched element. To get the value from all matched element, you need to iterate, there are various methods for that. `.each()` can be used to iterate and push the value in an array.

Here I have used `.map()` to get an array of attribute value for checked checkbox

```js
$('.calc').change(function() {
  var itemNames = $(".calc:checked").map(function() {
      return $(this).attr("data-selection-name")
    })
    .get() //Get an array
    .join(',') //Generate Comma seperate string;

  $("#quote-items").text(itemNames);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="poolSmallButton" name="pool" class="calc" value="500" data-selection-name="Small Pool" />
<input type="radio" id="poolMediumButton" name="pool" class="calc" value="1000" data-selection-name="Medium Pool" />

<input type="radio" id="landscapingSmallButton" name="landscaping" value="100" class="calc" data-selection-name="Small Landscaping" />
<input type="radio" id="landscapingMediumButton" name="landscaping" value="500" class="calc" data-selection-name="Medium Landscaping" />

<span id="quote-items" name="quote-items"></span>
```

Additionaly, You can use [Element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property to access `data-*` prefixed attribute like

```
this.dataset.selectionName;
```

instead of

```
$(this).attr("data-selection-name");
```

Comment: Just a side note: the [`data()` method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) returns the corresponding `data-whatever-you-want` attribute value so you can use `$(this).data("selection-name")` instead of `$(this).attr("data-selection-name")`

Comment: @CliffBurton, Very valid point, I prefer `Element.dataset` property

Answer (score 0):

How to

```
<input type="radio" id="poolSmallButton" name="pool" class="calc" value="500" data-selection-name="productname" ata-selection-price="productprice" />
```

```
$("#sonuc-v2").text(data-selection-price);
$("#sonuc-v2").text(data-selection-price);
```